# PHP Retrieving Value From Array or Object

Tags: php, oop

I believe I have been given object oriented php. I want to be able to print out "filename" from my object. I was reading that I do not want [storage:ArrayObject:private] but I do not know how to get rid of it or why it is there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

My class is:

```
class ProductImage extends TemplateContext {

public static function get_images($id) {

    $product_images = mysql_query("SELECT filename from product_images WHERE related_product_id = '" . $id. "' AND priority = 0 ORDER BY related_product_id ASC") or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());

    while ($product_image = mysql_fetch_array($product_images)) {
        $results[] = new self($product_image);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

}

My view is:

```
$id= '5';

print_r(ProductImage::get_images($id));
```

And my output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ProductImage Object
        (
            [ctx] => Array
                (
                )

            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product.png
                    [filename] => product.png
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The filename is stored in a private class property, you'll have to find or write a public get() method to retrieve it.

Comment: It would be nice to see the `__construct` that gets invoked when you do `new self(...)` there. It should be in your `ProductImage` class or one of it's ancestors. Also, `ArrayObject`s are very array like, you should be able to use it as an array anyways (with something like `$images[0]->storage['filename'])`.

Comment: Ah...Both the comments together made this make sense. Added both of those things and got it working. Thanks!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).